# Defining events

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand how my professor defined the events in the following question:

> A box contains three coins: two regular coins and one fake two-headed coin (probability
>   for heads is 1). You pick a coin at random and toss it. What is the probability that it lands heads up?

He defined the following events:

> Let C1 be the event that you choose a regular coin, let C2 be the event that you choose the two-headedcoin, let H be the event that the outcome is heads, and let T be the event that the outcome is tails.

Then he calculates:
$ P (H | C_1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P (H | C_2) = 1$

---

My question:

If $ P(H | C1) = \frac{P(H \cap C_1)}{P(C_1)} $, then what is: $P(H \cap C_1)$ (they don't contain the same element's form) ? Both of the sets $ H,C_1 $ contain different and **unrelated** elements.

$ C1= \{ coin_1 , coin_2 \} $

$ C2= \{ coin_3 \} $

$ H = \{ $ I don't understand what form of elements there are in this set $ \} $

Comment: First of all, shouldn't $P (H | C_2) = 1$?  Second, to answer your question: An event is a set of sample points.  I would not say "coin1" is a sample point.  Instead i would say "coin1, heads" is a sample point and "coin1, tails" is another sample point.  Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When choosing your probability space, $\Omega$, each outcome $\omega\in \Omega$ has to describe the entire situation. When you say $C_1=\{\text{coin 1},\text{coin 2}\}$, this is accounting for what coin was chosen, but not what the outcome of the flip was.

There are two random things: you choose the coin, then you flip it. Therefore, the probability space consists of all ordered pairs $(c,f)$, where $c$ is the coin chosen and $f$ is the result of the flip. There are $6$ outcomes in this space, all equally likely:
$$
(\text{coin 1},H), (\text{coin 1},T), (\text{coin 2},H),(\text{coin 2},T),(\text{coin 3},H),(\text{coin 3},H)
$$
Note that there are four outcomes corresponding to $C_1,$ there two outcomes corresponding to $C_2$, and four outcomes corresponding to $H$ (the four where the flip is heads). We also have that $H\cap C_1$ has a single outcome, $(\text{coin 1},H)$.

Comment: I thought that $\Omega$ is a set, then why $\Omega$ contain two identical elements: $(coin 3,H)$ ?

Comment: Good point. Technically, I should have written $(\text{coin 3}, H)$ and  $(\text{coin 3}, H')$, where $H$ is one of the heads and $H'$ is the head on the other side.

Comment: How about defining every three-pair: $(coin-number, side-index, result-of-flip)$ ? Will it work better than your last comment?

Comment: @StavAlfi That would work!

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I finally got it!